# Python 3.5.1 Extending a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

sorry to repost (I've just joined stack overflow 30 mins ago).
I don't think I explained in my previous post of my function.

```
def GetExtendedKeyword(message, newkeyword):
    while True:
        difference = len(message) - len(newkeyword)
        if difference > 0:
            newkeyword.extend(newkeyword[:difference]
            return newkeyword
        elif difference <= 0:
            return newkeyword
```

What I have are two lists, a message and keyword list. The program calculates the difference between them and if the keyword is shorter than the message list, the program will repeat the keywordlist by that difference.

For example the original keywordlist is `[0,1,5,2,5]` and the difference is 3, the end result should be `[0,1,5,2,5,0,1,5]`. The program doesn't like my code when it comes to longer keyword or message lists. Please help!

Comment: `list.extend(list[:n])`.  Don't use `list` as a name, though, because it conflicts with the built-in type.

Comment: Can `n` be larger than the list's length?

Comment: Sorry thats what I mean't. That was what I wrote for the code but sometime the list does not want to extend by that amount.

Comment: @Mureinik yes it can.

Comment: If `n` is larger than the list's length, do you want it to start over at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
l = [0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9]
l.extend(l[:n]) #extend l with the first n elements of l
```

This only works for n < len(l) ...

Comment: Can you expand this and explain how it works? This popped up in the review queue.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount can be larger than the list length, you can do this:

```
def extend(lst, n):
    nfull = n / len(lst) + 1
    nrem = n % len(lst)
    return lst*nfull+lst[:nrem]

lst = [0,1,5,4,2,9]
print extend(lst, 3)
# [0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9, 0, 1, 5]
print extend(lst, 7)
# [0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9, 0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9, 0]
```

Comment: def GetExtendedKeyword(message, newkeyword):

    while True:
        difference = len(message) - len(newkeyword)
        if difference > 0:
            newkeyword.extend(newkeywordp[:difference])
            print(newkeyword)
            return newkeyword
        elif difference <= 0:
            return newkeyword

Answer (score 0):

> list.extend(L)  Extend the list by appending all the items in the
>   given list; equivalent to  a[len(a):] = L.

It's sentence from Python Documentation. I think it is the best place where you should looking for a help. Acording to documentation, your code should look like this:

```
listOne = [0,1,5,4,2,9]
listOne.extend(listOne[:n])
```

I wonder to help you.

Comment: Hello,

That is the way I originally coded my function but for certain lengths of lists, the program did not want to extend it. 

The idea is that I have two lists (a message list and a keyword list), the program calculates the difference between them in length (message - keyword), and, if the difference is greater than 0, the program will extend the keyword list to match the message list.

Comment: Use function len() to know how many elements are in the lists. The code is there
message = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
keyword = [1,2,3]
n = len(message)-len(keyword)
if n>0:
 keyword.extend(message[n:])
print (message,keyword)